# Gremlin : Get total count of a label and project the count

Tags: graph, graphql, gremlin, janusgraph

I am trying to perform a query where I can retrieve all the total count of a label , say 'user' and I have a property known as 'type' having value of label name.

**Query :**

```
g.V().has('type','user').project('count').by(__.count())
```

**Output :**

```
==>[count:1]
==>[count:1]
==>[count:1]
==>[count:1]
==>[count:1]
==>[count:1]
==>[count:1]
==>[count:1]
==>[count:1]
==>[count:1]
....
```

**Expected :**

```
==>[count:10]
```

Need help on the query for getting the prescribed output.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

g.V().has('type','user').fold().project('count').by(unfold().count())

The fold() step assures that a projection on a single object is carried out. The unfold() step makes that the individual elements of the list can be counted.

Comment: Also found out after the fold() step we have to again traverse from the beginning. g.V().has('type','user').fold().project('count,'friend_id').by(unfold().count()).by(V().has('type','user').both('friend_of').id().fold()).toList()